# Are there any math rules for creating a fluid CSS template without borders overlapping?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a template for a page (you can see it [here](http://85.94.221.106/provintegra/)) and I'm trying to use proportional height and width. I'm having troubles with borders. I think there is some math calculation to do because I want to have pixel perfect borders for each div (that means that two adjacent divs should be separed only by a 1px border) and all divs contained in a container div should use all the available space (I hope you understand what I mean).

You can find the source code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3PW7y/)

Thx in advance for any suggestions on how to achieve this.

Comment: create a fiddle for your code..go to jsfiddle.net

Comment: thx for the suggestion i'll do it right now!

Comment: It's not a case of "math rules" when mixing percentages and pixels. Which browsers do you care about supporting? Does IE7 matter?

Comment: No, i'd say IE8, chrome, firefox 4

Comment: Anyway, having a fixed height and knowing the number of divs i thought there was some rule to calculate the percentage to use...maybe i'm wrong!

Comment: For sure you can calculate this, but not in CSS. Have a look at my answer. Maybe you can go that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you will have to modify your HTML and your css a bit to achieve such a result.
Elements with a width of 50% and a 1px border will be larger than 50% in the box model. So wrap your contents in another div and give that div the border. the outer div should get the 50% width. Also use only top and left borders.

I've modified the left part of your fiddle to give you an impression how it could work.

http://jsfiddle.net/3PW7y/2/

Comment: Thanx this is exactly what i was trying to achieve! :)